# Remote Python Connection

Tags: python, connection

I have a project I need to complete, looking for ideas or suggestions how to achieve it or where to find further information.

I have a python script already written & working using selenium & beautifulsoup.

I need to create a website whereby a visitor to my website will enter third party website login information in this case: a username & pin code which gives access to a third party website I need to login to.

Then the python script will open a webpage, enter login information & go to work mining data from the third party website the user has given me login details for. The mined data then needs to be stored somewhere on the web server or emailed to an email account I own for later processing.

The pin code the user will send is only valid for 30 minutes from the time the user requests it so the login has to be made while the user is visting the website.

A simpler version of this, is instead of running the python script automatically, once the user gives his login details. My website automatically opens a secure connection to the third party website which will stay logged in without timeout. That I will then be able to visit later.

This could also involve me leaving my personal computer switched on & opening a new port every time a new connection is made so I can open that website at a later date on my laptop using chrome debugging tools.

It could also involve me hosting my website on my own laptop & using a CDN to speed up the intial pages of my website the user visits.

Any suggestions about a good way to do this would be much appreciated.....

Comment: This sounds like a phishing scam??

Comment: Hi - no it isn't, this is a sytem for users to run some software so they can check their own accounts online.